# How to find fourier transform of $e^{-x^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

I want to find the fourier transform of $e^{-x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx-x^2}\,dx$ using contour integration.

I consider the rectangular contour $C$ with verticies $\pm R, \pm R + ik$

Then $f(z) = e^{ikz - z^2}$  is holomorphic on $C$ so $\int_C f(z) \,dz = 0$.

I tried parameterizing as such:
$$C_1 : z = x \quad -R \leq x \leq R$$
$$C_2 : z = R + iky \quad 0 \leq y \leq 1$$
$$C_3 : z = -x + ik \quad R\leq x\leq R$$
$$C_4 : z = -R + ik(1-y) \quad 0 \leq y \leq 1$$

But then I find $\int_{C_1} = \int_{C_3}$ and $\int_{C_2} = \int_{C_4}$ which gives me $\int_{C_1}= -\int_{C_3}$

Which doesn't seem helpful. How should I approach this problem?

Comment: *Hint* Can you prove that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm e^{-(x-\mathrm ik/2)^2}\mathrm dx$ does not depend on $k$ ?

Comment: Do you *have* to use contour integration?  Because there are other easy tricks for this integral!

Comment: @RobertLewis I'm trying to get practice in with contour integration, so it's the preferable method.

Comment: @Tom-Tom could this be done by looking at a similiar contour integral but with $f(z) = e^{z^2}$?

Comment: Contour integration is typically used when the function has poles. You chose a function that does not have poles. Hence other methods are now preferable.